# How to convert an Ubuntu package/repository to Alpine in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile, alpine-linux

Currently I have this `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# https://github.com/tesseract-shadow/tesseract-ocr-re
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common && add-apt-repository -y ppa:alex-p/tesseract-ocr
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr-all
RUN apt-get install -y git build-essential cmake
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg

# Install Node and NPM
RUN apt-get install nodejs -y && apt-get install npm -y
```

The size of the image is too big so I searched for alternatives and found about Alpine.

I'm stuck with this one

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add --update ffmpeg cmake nodejs npm
```

Looking at the aline edge repository, I can't seem to find `tesseract-ocr-all` and no idea how to do `apt-get install -y software-properties-common && add-apt-repository -y ppa:alex-p/tesseract-ocr` in alpine.

Are there any resources that can help me through this? Should I make my own Alpine image for those packages/repositories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alpine package name is [tesseract-ocr](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/tesseract-ocr), you can check here the [releases](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/releases) or alpine [repository](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/tesseract-ocr).

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add --update --no-cache ffmpeg cmake nodejs npm tesseract-ocr
```

If you are interested in the beta version you may check [here](https://github.com/i-net-software/docker-boxes/tree/master/tesseract-alpine).

Always try to add `--no-cache` option allows to not cache the index locally, which keeps containers small.

Comment: I am trying this one now. Thank you! Didn't know tesseract-ocr is the equivalent package of tesseract-ocr-all.